# Smooch - How can I update (change) one of conversations in history

Tags: smooch

I'm developing some service using Smooch.

I'd like to update ( or change ) specific message in conversation history.

Is it possible? If it is, how can I do that?

Thanks for all of your hint. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Smooch does not support editing a message in place. The nearest workarounds you have are:

- You can delete a single message https://docs.smooch.io/rest/#delete-single-message
- You can delete all of a user's messages (without deleting the user or their associated clients) https://docs.smooch.io/rest/#delete-all-messages